# Should I store generated code in source control

Tags: version-control, code-generation

This is a debate I'm taking a part in. I would like to get more opinions and points of view.

We have some classes that are generated in build time to handle DB operations (in This specific case, with SubSonic, but I don't think it is very important for the question). The generation is set as a pre-build step in Visual Studio. So every time a developer (or the official build process) runs a build, these classes are generated, and then compiled into the project.

Now some people are claiming, that having these classes saved in source control could cause confusion, in case the code you get, doesn't match what would have been generated in your own environment.

I would like to have a way to trace back the history of the code, even if it is usually treated as a black box.

Any arguments or counter arguments?

---

UPDATE: I asked this question since I really believed there is one definitive answer. Looking at all the responses, I could say with high level of certainty, that there is no such answer. The decision should be made based on more than one parameter. Reading the answers below could provide a very good guideline to the types of questions you should be asking yourself when having to decide on this issue.

I won't select an accepted answer at this point for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: You may be interested in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739391/how-far-do-you-take-version-control

Comment: I'd like to say, in the case of SubSonic, it might be interesting to keep in source control as a way to also track (some) database changes easily, in case you don't have any other way of tracing the history of your database.

Comment: In my thinking, the main problem is that different developers don't get the same result when generating the classes. The config for generating them should be checked in, and give consistent builds in all developer environments.

Comment: Don't know how to do this, however I think this question should be closed now as it's too open to opinion and discussion without relating tightly to specific source control systems or specific types of generated files.

Comment: This is a great question, but it is too opinion-based for SO, as indicated by the multiple conflicting answers, and the OP's own comment to this effect.

Answer (score 62):

Saving it in source control is more trouble than it's worth.

You have to do a commit every time you do a build for it to be any value.

Generally we leave generated code( idl, jaxb stuff, etc) outside source control where I work and it's never been a problem

Comment: I disagree with "you have to do a commit every time you build".  This should cause no extra commit because the only thing that should affect the commit is a change to the code which hence changes the generated source.  So in effect you have to commit the generated code only when you're already commiting the change to the source of the generated code.

Comment: Agree with JaredPar. Also your code-generator may be an external tool, and if you update it, the generated code may change and therefore you may need to commit changes. But in this case I would really want to see the changes in source-control anyway.

Comment: Different tools may generate different sources (at least they may differ in comments or code formatting). E.g. Idea adds "generated by idea" comment while Eclipse does not.

Comment: The opinion is divided, marking this one as an answer would convey wrong message.

Answer (score 45):

Put it in source code control.  The advantage of having the history of everything you write available for future developers outweighs the minor pain of occasionally rebuilding after a sync.

Comment: Thats not an advantage - since the code that created it is checked in you already have 'everything you write' available for future developers.

Comment: @Shane, i strongly disagree.  Having the code that created it does not equal having the code.  Any extra steps that must be included for generation is extra annoyance when tracking down a bug.  It's much simpler to go through the history of the code than it is to check out N versions of the file and re-generate N versions of the generated code.

Comment: It is sometimes beneficial to have the generated files in source control. For example if you upgrade a component, in this case SubSonic, you can easily detect changes in the generated source. This could be useful in tracking down bugs and issues. I wouldn't add all generated code to source control. Sometimes it is very useful. Most source control systems will let you do a diff to see if the files have really changed although it maybe more of a manual process if you have to manually revert the files even though the only change is the timestamp.

Comment: +1 having a repository for your application is most valuable when the *working application* is in the repository, not just the tools to eventually create the working application. Minimize friction.

Comment: +1 Anything you need to debug should be in source control. Generated or not...its code.

Comment: Trying to debug based on intermediate code you didn't generate from original source just makes my head hurt. :(

Comment: By that logic you should also check in your compiled object files, libraries and executables.

Comment: @Laurence, I disagree.  DLL's provide no historical value in the sense that you cannot understand the history by examining diffs.

Comment: How often do you need to look at the history of the generated files as opposed to the history of the source files they were generated from? In my experience: virtually never (and I've worked on a code generator for the last 7 years). The extra costs imposed by checking in the generated code aren't huge for each change, but they add up quickly. Every single change that modifies a source to a generated file has an extra source of mistakes ("oops, forgot to check in generated file") and is more tedious to deal with in code review. Writing a script to regenerate historical versions is trivial.

Comment: @Laurence i disagree on 2 of your points. First I find it to be extremely useful especially if i'm not familiar with the tool that generated the code. The original language is meaningless, all I care about is "what got compiled". Second, writing a script is not trivial. Your script must take into account all versions of the code generator and know for which change list which code generator was used. That is certainly not a trivial problem

Comment: What kind of code generator are you using where "the original language is meaningless"? As for the point about keeping track of what versions of your tools you're using to build each version of the code, you already need to solve that problem for your entire toolchain. After all, how do you expect to backport a bug to an older version of your product unless you know what version of the compiler and linker you were using back then? A code generator is no different from your C++/Java/C# compiler. The fact that you might be able to read its output is immaterial: its input is the source.

Comment: In some cases the "original" no longer exists.  Consider a DAL (NHibernate, LINQ, etc.) generated from a database.  Unless you also snapshot your database, the input to your generator will never exist in exactly the same state again...

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves.  I don't think it's black and while.  For example, code generated by Visual Studio designers, and by tools such as the MSDataSetGenerator or ResXFileCodeGenerator is generally checked in to source control. But I can imagine situations where I'd generate files using a preprocessor that aren't in source control.

Comment: @Laurence, as to what code generator I'm talking about is mainly aimed at several old hacky generators I've seen in source trees.  The weird format the original and long since left author decided upon is meaningless.  All I cared about in that case was the code that made it into the product.  I don't feel the rest of your comment addresses how writing a script to re-generate the code would be a trivial operation.  How for instance would you get your generator to understand that we use version X of the generator change list Y?  Much easier to just browse the source history

Comment: @Joe: the original question was talking about code generated by the build process (ie: "every time a developer ... runs a build, these classes are generated"). Code generated by your IDE is a very different situation because there is no "source" for the generated code.

Comment: @JaredPar: you have to deal with the issue of what tools are used in your build for each version of your code regardless of code generators. Checking in your generated code doesn't help for those build artifacts you aren't checking in or in cases when you need to change the source of generated code in an old version (say, to backport a bug fix). It's not only an incomplete solution, but a poor one as it imposes a recurring cost on every change that affects your generated code. Solve the real problem: keep either your build tools or pointers to them in source control.

Comment: @Laurence,  I fail to follow your argument as to why checking in *everything* is an incomplete solution.  Yes you must have generators available, and likely checked in, for every version of the product you build.  That is not the issue I am raising.  You said it would be trivial to write a code generation script.  I am stating that even with all of the generators checked in, writing a script to regenerate all of the versions of the actual compiled code is a non-trivial operation.  It involves lots of syncing, building, mapping versions to generators, branch issue, etc ...

Comment: (cont) As a developer I want to be able quickly view the history of code that went my product over time.  Typically, the primary goal is to identify when a particular change made it into the product.  The easiest and simplest way to do this is to have all source code checked in period.  Then I can rely on my source control server to do the job it was designed to do.  Show me the history of my code.

Comment: @JaredPar: I don't know what your build environment looks like, but in mine the script to sync to a particular version and then build the project using the right version of the code generators is 2 lines. Roughly: "p4 sync @changelist; build projectname"

Comment: @JaredPar: I think the fundamental problem is that you're using a code generator where "the original language is meaningless". Because you're not fixing that problem you end up having what are really workarounds. It makes no sense to have a code generator where its output is easier to deal with than its input. If you find yourself in that situation, go ahead and check in the generated code, but then also delete the code generator and the source as they aren't adding any value.

Comment: @Laurence, sure that will work in most environments if you sync the world.  I find that terrifically unacceptable and very costly.  You also must generate all versions of the file and the script to run the diffs.  Building one version is easy, building a history is not.

Comment: @Laurence, the original language being meaningless is an extreme example of a more general problem.  The more general problem is you simply cannot expect every developer to be able to look at any code generator file and know exactly what the output will be.  There are quite simply too many generators and differences between versions of the same generator to make this assumption.  At the end of the day what matters is what source was actually used to build the product and hence should be checked in.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You already claimed that you can identify which input files led to changes in your generated files. After all, that's how you know that you need to resubmit them to source control. So you can use the same logic to determine which files to sync to.

Comment: As for "the original language being meaningless is an extreme example": I agree, but it's also the only case where your argument holds water. The whole point of having a code generator is that its input is more concise than its output. Every code generator I've worked with generates code that is *far* more complicated than the input to the code generator. I cannot remember a single instance of someone wanting to look at the history of the generated code.

Comment: @Laurence, I disagree that I am contradicting myself.  The only way to *definitively* produce the exact same file is to sync the file and all of it's dependencies, including the generator dependecies (transitive and direct).  In a project of medium or greater size the safest way to do this is to sync everything.

Comment: @Laurence, Yes generator code can be complex.  But that is not the primary issue.  What is valuable about checking the code into source code control is being able to view the history of the code.  This is oftentimes much more valuable than having the actual code.

Comment: @Laurence,  There are many cases where history is important.  I've already cited identifying a regression.  Another is Beta / RC bug fixes.  These often have to be reviewed by many devs (and often non-devs) outside your organization who you will not be familiar with every generator you use.  They simply don't care what I changed in an XML file because the change is meaningless to them.  They want to see how my changes effect they shipping code.  Having a version history of the file provides this function.

Comment: The contradiction is that you claim that it's too hard to figure out which files to sync yet at the same time you think it's easy to figure out when a generated file needs to be resubmitted. These amount to the same problem. The question is, do you want to have to figure it out on every single change (pretty much guaranteeing screw-ups) or do you want to do it the handful of times that you need to look at the historical changes to a generated file (if ever -- where I work we use a bunch of code generators which generate hundreds of files and not once have I heard of anyone needing to do this).

Comment: I also have my doubts about non-devs preferring to see your generated code over an XML file. :-)

Comment: @Laurence, it's simple to know when a generated file needs to be submitted.  If I change a generator source, build and the file is different, I should submit.  What is difficult about that?  If the file is unchanged most / some source code control providers will simply ignore that file during check in.

Comment: @Laurence, I understand the doubts about non devs wanting to look at code but I assure this indeed true.  Half of preparing for a RC / Beta bug is figuring out how to explain a code diff to people who are not every day devs.  The first time I had to do this was an ... interesting experience.

Comment: @Laurence @JaredPear: I have never needed to review revision history for a generated file in 10 years of coding. I agree with Laurence's point that the input is easier to deal with then the output. The generated code should be a black box, if you use it, you should understand its input. In my experience, the real logic is in the input, or the code generator. Therefore, the bug will have to be fixed either in the code generator or in the input file.

Comment: @Juan, just because you haven't had the experience doesn't mean it's not common.  I've had to review generated code files several time (doesn't make my experience normal either)

Comment: @JaredPear, I mentioned my experience, but the real point of my comment is that the real logic that may need to be fixed is in the input or the code generator, not the output. Therefore, it's a lot more likely that inspecting that history will give you more insight into the bug.

Comment: @Juan in crunch time late in the cycle changing a generator which would affect hundreds of files in a project is simply not a good suggestion when you could just change one of them.

Comment: @JaredPar Sorry, but hacking a generated file by hand does not sound like a better alternative. You do that and now you have some files that are generated and some that are hand maintained.

Comment: @Juan hacking a single generated file on a release only branch has no long term maintenance issues.

Comment: I guess you don't consider having the bug reappear the next time you run the code generator to be a long term maintenance issue...

Comment: @JaredPar, Hopefully in the two and a half years you've had to experience these issues, you've changed your mind on this one.  I strongly believe that committing source files that are generated as part of the build is a flawed approach.

Comment: @Kieveli nope. Years later I'm much more committed to the idea of storing generated code in source code control. My current code base has at least 10 generator programs in it.  It's ridiculous to expect a dev 5 years from now to understand intimately how those 10 generators worked when investigating a bug.

Comment: I agree with the critique to this. A code generator transforms manually written input to automatically generated output — just like a compiler, a linker, or any other build tool. Additionally to the source code, you will need all your build tools in the appropriate version in order to recreate an older build, there's no difference at all between compiler or any other code generator. Most companies I have seen store their release binaries somewhere, but none of them stored them in source control. (There's a reason it's called _"source"_ control, after all.)

Comment: @sbi in what way is generated source different from real source? It has bugs, it changes over time, it's necessary for debugging and it's the language in which the program is written

Answer (score 33):

Every time I want to show changes to a source tree on my own personal repo, all the 'generated files' will show up as having changed and need comitting.

I would prefer to have a cleaner list of modifications that only include real updates that were performed, and not auto-generated changes.

Leave them out, and then after a build, add an 'ignore' on each of the generated files.

Comment: Also, on updates, you can get strange conflicts that the VCS will consider as needing resolution, but will actually resolve themselves the next time you build.  Not to mention the clutter in the logs, which I consider even worse than the clutter in your local tree.

Comment: Where I'm at, they don't show up as 'having changed' unless they really have changed.  If they were regenerated but still have the same content so the only thing different is file create/modified dates, the system thinks they haven't changed and everything is fine.

Comment: +1 I only want to be responsible for what code I write, not some code that got generated by some toolkit that may have had issues at the time that now are impossible to duplicate (but someone could spend a lot of time trying.)

Comment: I've seen autogenerating tools that update the timestamp every time they run. I curse them.

Answer (score 31):

Look at it this way: do you check your object files into source control? Generated source files are build artifacts just like object files, libraries and executables. They should be treated the same. Most would argue that you shouldn't be checking generated object files and executables into source control. The same arguments apply to generated source.

If you need to look at the historical version of a generated file you can sync to the historical version of its sources and rebuild.

Checking generated files of any sort into source control is analogous to database denormalization. There are *occasionally* reasons to do this (typically for performance), but this should be done only with great care as it becomes much harder to maintain correctness and consistency once the data is denormalized.

Comment: How can you say that source files are comparable to object files? Object files are binary and not human readable. Anyway, "generated source file" is an oxymoron, it's either a source, or it's generated, it can't be both.

Comment: @CrisLuengo get your point about "generated source file" being an oxymoron, but it is not a term I invented. It's a commonly used term to refer to code that's generated, but in a language which is more typically used for human-written "source code". And in fact, my point is that "generated source files" are not actually source files, but build artifacts. Whether a file happens to be human readable or not is irrelevant when it comes to deciding whether it belongs in source control. True "source" files (ie: not generated) belong in source control. Generated files, regardless of format, do not.

Comment: All I'm saying is that "do you check your object files into source control?" is the wrong argument.  Object files are not comparable to generated human-readable code (or data) files. If you want to have an argument as to why not commit those to a repository, it has to be an argument that applies to those files, you cannot base it on a false equivalency.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The reason people think it's okay to commit generated source is itself because of a false equivalence. They think human-readable is the determining factor in deciding whether to commit a file to source control, but it is not. It is irrelevant. The real determining factor is whether the file is a "source" of information, or if it is generated from other sources. If you look at the arguments people make for committing generated source, you'll see that most of them apply equally to committing generated object files.

Comment: I’m not arguing either way about committing generated files. I’m just pointing out the wrong argument. Defending it with “other people also use false equivalences when arguing this topic” is not a good defence. ;)

Answer (score 20):

I would say that you should avoid adding any generated code (or other artifacts) to source control. If the generated code is the same for the given input then you could just check out the versions you want to diff and generate the code for comparison.

Comment: FYI, I've shared a script to do that comparison here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754923/105137

Answer (score 19):

I call the DRY principle. If you already have the "source files" in the repository which are used to generate these code files at build time, there is no need to have the same code committed "twice".

Also, you might avert some problems this way if for example the code generation breaks someday.

Comment: "if for example the code generation breaks someday" then I would **love** to have the generated files at hand, for example, in the source control.

Answer (score 19):

No, for three reasons.

1. Source code is everything necessary and sufficient to reproduce a snapshot of your application as of some current or previous point in time - nothing more and nothing less. Part of what this implies is that someone is responsible for everything checked in. Generally I'm happy to be responsible for the code I write, but not the code that's generated as a consequence of what I write.
2. I don't want someone to be tempted to try to shortcut a build from primary sources by using intermediate code that may or may not be current (and more importantly that I don't want to accept responsibility for.) And't it's too tempting for some people to get caught up in a meaningless process about debugging conflicts in intermediate code based on partial builds.
3. Once it's in source control, I accept responsibility for a. it being there, b. it being current, and c. it being reliably integratable with everything else in there. That includes removing it when I'm no longer using it. The less of that responsibility the better.

Comment: The "may or may not be current" is key to me, as that is a potential source of insidious bugs depending on how the checked in generated code is used (e.g. as a 'cached' version in build pipelines).

Answer (score 14):

I really don't think you should check them in.

Surely any change in the generated code is either going to be noise - changes between environments, or changes as a result of something else - e.g. a change in your DB. If your DB's creation scripts (or any other dependencies) are in source control then why do you need the generated scripts as well?

Answer (score 10):

The general rule is **no**, but if it takes time to generate the code (because of DB access, web services, etc.) then you might want to save a cached version in the source control and save everyone the pain.

Your tooling also need to be aware of this and handle checking-out from the source control when needed, too many tools decide to check out from the source control without any reason.
A good tool will use the cached version without touching it (nor modifying the time steps on the file).

Also you need to put big warning inside the generated code for people to not modify the file, a warning at the top is not enough, you have to repeat it every dozen lines.

Answer (score 10):

There is a special case where you want to check in your generated files: when you may need to build on systems where tools used to generate the other files aren't available. The classic example of this, and one I work with, is Lex and Yacc code. Because we develop a runtime system that has to build and run on a huge variety of platforms and architectures, we can only rely on target systems to have C and C++ compilers, not the tools necessary to generate the lexing/parsing code for our interface definition translator. Thus, when we change our grammars, we check in the generated code to parse it.

Comment: Similar comments apply to autoconf/automake-generated files; most people check in their ./configure and Makefile.in files, even though they're generated - most users (and many developers) won't need to rebuild them, and by checking those files in, you don't need autotools installed to build.

Comment: Yeah, we store our configure script and our generated Make dependencies in version control, too.

Answer (score 9):

We don't store generated DB code either: since it is generated, you can get it at will at any given version from the source files. Storing it would be like storing bytecode or such.

Now, you need to ensure the code generator used at a given version is available! Newer versions can generate different code...

Answer (score 9):

Leave it out.

If you're checking in generated files you're doing something wrong. What's wrong may differ, it could be that your build process is inefficient, or something else, but I can't see it *ever* being a good idea. History should be associated with the source files, not the generated ones.

It just creates a headache for people who then end up trying to resolve differences, find the files that are no longer generated by the build and then delete them, etc.

A world of pain awaits those who check in generated files!

Answer (score 7):

There are good arguments both for and against presented here.
For the record, I build the T4 generation system in Visual Studio and our default out-of-the-box option causes generated code to be checked in. You have to work a bit harder if you prefer not to check in.

For me the key consideration is diffing the generated output when either the input or generator itself is updated.

If you don't have your output checked in, then you have to take a copy of all generated code before upgrading a generator or modifying input in order to be able to compare that with the output from the new version.  I think this is a fairly tedious process, but with checked in output, it's a simple matter of diffing the new output against the repository.

At this point, it is reasonable to ask "Why do you care about changes in generated code?" (Especially as compared to object code.)
I believe there are a few key reasons, which come down to the current state of the art rather than any inherent problem.

1. You craft handwritten code that meshes tightly with generated code. That's not the case on the whole with obj files these days.  When the generated code changes, it's sadly quite often the case that some handwritten code needs to change to match.  Folks often don't observe a high degree of backwards compatibility with extensibility points in generated code.
2. Generated code simply changes its behavior.  You wouldn't tolerate this from a compiler, but in fairness, an application-level code generator is targeting a different field of problem with a wider range of acceptable solutions. It's important to see if assumptions you made about previous behavior are now broken.
3. You just don't 100% trust the output of your generator from release to release.  There's a lot of value to be had from generator tools even if they aren't built and maintained with the rigor of your compiler vendor.  Release 1.0 might have been perfectly stable for your application but maybe 1.1 has a few glitches for your use case now.  Alternatively you change input values and find that you are exercisig a new piece of the generator that you hadn't used before - potentially you get surprised by the results.

Essentially all of these things come down to tool maturity - most business app code generators aren't close to the level that compilers or even lex/yacc-level tools have been for years.

Answer (score 6):

In some projects I add generated code to source control, but it really depends. My basic guideline is if the generated code is an intrinsic part of the compiler then I won't add it. If the generated code is from an external tool, such as SubSonic in this case, then I would add if to source control. If you periodically upgrade the component then I want to know the changes in the generated source in case bugs or issues arise.

As far as generated code needing to be checked in, a worst case scenario is manually differencing the files and reverting the files if necessary. If you are using svn, you can add a pre-commit hook in svn to deny a commit if the file hasn't really changed.

Answer (score 6):

arriving a bit late ... anyway ...

Would you put compiler's intermediate file into source version control ? 
In case of code generation, by definition the source code is the input of the generator while the generated code can be considered as intermediate files between the "real" source and the built application.

So I would say: don't put generated code under version control, but the generator and its input.

Concretely, I work with a code generator I wrote: I never had to maintain the generated source code under version control. I would even say that since the generator reached a certain maturity level, I didn't have to observe the contents of generated code although the input (for instance model description) changed.

Answer (score 4):

The job of configuration management (of which version control is just one part) is to be able to do the following:

- Know which changes and bug fixes have gone into every delivered build.
- Be able to reproduce exactly any delivered build, starting from the original source code.  Automatically generated code does not count as "source code" regardless of the language.

The first one ensures that when you tell the client or end user "the bug you reported last week is fixed and the new feature has been added" they don't come back two hours later and say "no it hasn't".  It also makes sure they don't say "Why is it doing X?  We never asked for X".

The second one means that when the client or end user reports a bug in some version you issued a year ago you can go back to that version, reproduce the bug, fix it, and prove that it was your fix has eliminated the bug rather than some perturbation of compiler and other fixes.

This means that your compiler, libraries etc also need to be part of CM.

So now to answer your question: if you can do all the above then you don't need to record any intermediate representations, because you are guaranteed to get the same answer anyway.  If you can't do all the above then all bets are off because you can never guarantee to do the same thing twice and get the same answer.  So you might as well put all your .o files under version control as well.

Answer (score 4):

Both side have valid and reasonable argument, and it's difficult to agree on something common. Version Control Systems (VCSs) tracks the files
developers put into it, and have the assumption that the files inside VCS are hand crafted by developers, and developers are interested in the history
and change between any revision of the files. This assumption equalize the two concepts, "I want to get this file when I do checkout." and "I am
interested in the change of this file."

Now, the arguments from both sides could be rephrase like this:

- "I want to get all these generated files when I do checkout, because I don't have the tool to generate them in this machine."
- "I should not put them into VCS, since I am not interested in the change of this file."

Fortunately, it seems that the two requirements are not conflicting fundamentally. With some extension of current VCSs, it should be possible to have
both. In other words, it's a false dilemma. If we ponder a while, it's not hard to realize that the problem stems from the assumption VCSs hold. VCSs
should distinguish the files, which are hand crafted by developers, from files which are not hand crafted by developers, but just happens to be inside
this VCS. For the first category of files, which we call source files (code) usually, VCSs have done great job now. For the latter category, VCSs have
not had such concept yet, as far as I know.

### Summary

I will take git as one example to illustrate what I mean.

- `git status` should not show generated files by default.
- `git commit` should include generated files as snapshot.
- `git diff` should not show generated files by default.

### PS

Git hooks could be used as a workaround, but it would be great if git supports it natively. `gitignore` doesn't meet our requirement, for ignored
files won't go into VCSs.`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

I would argue for.  If you're using a continuous integration process that checks out the code, modifies the build number, builds the software and then tests it, then it's simpler and easier to just have that code as part of your repository.

Additionally, it's part and parcel of every "snapshot" that you take of your software repository.  If it's part of the software, then it should be part of the repository.

Comment: I love the drive by -1's.  If you don't agree, don't vote it up - vote up the other answers.  Save the downvotes for a wrong answer. This is a subjective question.

Answer (score 3):

I (regretfully) wind up putting a lot of derived sources under source control because I work remotely with people who either can't be bothered to set up a proper build environment or who don't have the skills to set it up so that the derived sources are built exactly right.  (And when it comes to Gnu autotools, I am one of those people myself!  I can't work with three different systems each of which works with a different version of autotools—and only that version.)

This sort of difficulty probably applies more to part-time, volunteer, open-source projects than to paid projects where the person paying the bills can insist on a uniform build environment.

When you do this, you're basically committing to building the derived files only at one site, or only at properly configured sites.  Your Makefiles (or whatever) should be set up to notice where they are running and should refuse to re-derive sources unless they know they are running at a safe build site.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is "It Depends". It depends upon what the client's needs are.
If you can roll back code to a particular release and stand up to any external audit's without it, then you're still not on firm ground. As dev's we need to consider not just 'noise', pain and disk space, but the fact that we are tasked with the role of generating intellectual property and there may be legal ramifications. Would you be able to prove to a judge that you're able to regenerate a web site exactly the way a customer saw it two years ago?

I'm not suggesting you save or don't save gen'd files, whichever way you decide if you're not involving the Subject Matter Experts of the decision you're probably wrong.

My two cents.

Comment: You make an interesting point, and don't take the downvote personally, it's just that for practical purposes in often fast-paced dev environments, this just isn't practical.  Why in any case would auto-generated code carry any data that relates to content or IP? I would suggest that clients in general wouldn't be able to grasp the implications of source-controlling auto-generated code and probably in general shouldn't be offered this option.  IMHO it's too much overhead and expense, to attend to a hypothetical and unlikely legal situation.

Comment: In the domain that I'm in currently, insurance our (very large) client keeps EVERYTHING for a minimum of 10 years. We build sophisticated tools to gen up WCF services. Clients keep the generated code, templates, the whole thing. But that is my client. Guess you missed the point I was making that "It depends on the client needs" & " whichever way you decide if you're not involving the Subject Matter Experts of the decision you're probably wrong." If somehow that's a bad answer, or it makes you feel better giving a -1, glad to have helped. Refer to 'womp' on the comment above my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends. Ultimately, the goal is to be able to reproduce what you had if need be. If you are able to regenerate your binaries exactly, there is no need to store them. but you need to remember that in order to recreate your stuff you will probably need your exact configuration you did it with in the first place, and that not only means your source code, but also your build environment, your IDE, maybe even other libraries, generators or stuff, in the exact configuration (versions) you have used.

I have run into trouble in projects were we upgraded our build environment to newer versions or even to another vendors', where we were unable to recreate the exact binaries we had before. This is a real pain when the binaries to be deplyed depend on a kind of hash, especially in secured environment, and the recreated files somehow differ because of compiler upgrades or whatever.

So, would you store generated code: I would say no. The binaries or deliverables that are released, including the tools that you reproduced them with I would store. And then, there is no need to store them in source control, just make a good backup of those files.

Comment: "that not only means your source code, but also your build environment, your IDE, maybe even other libraries, generators or stuff"\n
That's all stuff I would check in. If you build your compiler from source on every developer machine as part of the same build as your apps (ie: you type 'make' once), check in the source. If you don't, then check in the binaries

Answer (score 1):

I would say that yes you want to put it under source control.  From a configuration management standpoint EVERYTHING that is used to produce a software build needs to be controlled so that it can be recreated.  I understand that generated code can easily be recreated, but an argument can be made that it is not the same since the date/timestamps will be different between the two builds.  In some areas such as government, they require a lot of times this is what's done.

Comment: Do you check in your object files (.o)?

Answer (score 1):

In general, generated code need not be stored in source control because the revision history of this code can be traced by the revision history of the code that generated it!

However, it sounds the OP is using the generated code as the data access layer of the application instead of manually writing one.  In this case, I would change the build process, and commit the code to source control because it is a critical component of the runtime code.  This also removes the dependency on the code generation tool from the build process in case the developers need to use different version of the tool for different branches.

It seems that the code only needs to be generated once instead of every build.  When a developer needs to add/remove/change the way an object accesses the database, the code should be generated again, just like making manual modifications.  This speeds up the build process, allows manual optimizations to be made to the data access layer, and history of the data access layer is retained in a simple manner.

Comment: I disagree.  If you make it a manual process, it *will* get broken, and no one will notice until it comes time to rerun it.  If it's generated every day on your build servers (and every developers machine when the do a 'clean' build), you won't get surprised.

Comment: If the data access layer code is checked into source control, there should be no surprises because people will be forced to update code.  If someone happens to change the version of the code generation tool on the build machine and the developers have old versions on their development machine (different branch of code, perhaps), then there will be headaches.  I'm suggesting that he removes the code generation step out of the build process, since they are not the maintainers of the code generator.

Answer (score 1):

If it is part of the source code then it should be put in source control regardless of who or what generates it. You want your source control to reflect the current state of your system without having to regenerate it.

Comment: "without having to regenerate it." so you check in compiled binaries? Do you also check in a version of the target platform as well? That strategy won't scale well. :(

Comment: And that gets me a down vote?? Of course you don't check in compiled binaries (unless they are from third party libraries) since they can be regenerated from your source code. I was talking about having to regenerate the generated code not the binaries. But hey, if you want to misinterpret what I'm saying then go right ahead...

Comment: This answer wasn't worth a downvote! At the very least, it seems sound to put generated code in SC (maybe in a clearly identified place) so that at the very least you can compare the hash of the code used to generate the object against the new code you're going to generate for a new build. Interesting how polarizing this question is.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely have the generated code in source control, for many reasons.  I'm reiterating what a lot of people have already said, but some reasons I'd do it are

1. With codefiles in source control, you'll potentially be able to compile the code without using your Visual Studio pre-build step.
2. When you're doing a full comparison between two versions, it would be nice to know if the generated code changed between those two tags, without having to manually check it.
3. If the code generator itself changes, then you'll want to make sure that the changes to the generated code changes appropriately.  i.e. If your generator changes, but the output isn't supposed to change, then when you go to commit your code, there will be no differences between what was previously generated and what's in the generated code now.

Comment: And your code generator itself isn't in source control because...?

Comment: @Jeffrey: I never said the code generator wasn't in source control.

Comment: I know, I'm just teasing. :-) I've found that a lot of CodeDom-based code generators like to produce their output in random order, though, so for repeatability (and thus the ability to readily tell if the generated code changes from run to run) I've written a routine that sorts the contents of a `CodeCompileUnit` into a canonical order.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave generated files **out** of a source tree, but put it **in** a separate build tree.

e.g. workflow is

1. checkin/out/modify/merge source normally (w/o any generated files)
2. At appropriate occasions, check out source tree into a clean build tree
3. After a build, checkin all "important" files ("real" source files, executables + generated source file) that must be present for auditing/regulatory purposes. This gives you a history of all appropriate generated code+executables+whatever, at time increments that are related to releases / testing snapshots, etc. and decoupled from day-to-day development.

There's probably good ways in Subversion/Mercurial/Git/etc to tie the history of the real source files in both places together.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are very strong and convincing opinions on both sides. I would recommend reading all the top voted answers, and then deciding what arguments apply to your specific case.

UPDATE: I asked this question since I really believed there is one definitive answer. Looking at all the responses, I could say with high level of certainty, that there is no such answer. The decision should be made based on more than one parameter. Reading the other answers could provide a very good guideline to the types of questions you should be asking yourself when having to decide on this issue.