# Where to put code generated from proto files in Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang, protocol-buffers

This is more of a search for a reasonable approach than a problem. I'm using [gpb](https://github.com/tomas-abrahamsson/gpb) to generate Erlang bindings out of `*.proto` files (Google Protocol Buffers). The structure of my OTP application is default:

```
/ebin
/include
/priv
/src
```

Given a `*.proto` file, let's say `person.proto`, gpb generates `person.erl`, including methods for decoding and encoding messages, and `person.hrl` which holds record definitions, as protocol buffers are implemented as records in Erlang. The locations where these generated files are put can be passed for compilation, but I wonder where to put them. There's a [debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893913/should-i-store-generated-code-in-source-control) whether or not to put generated source code under version control, but I would like to omit it. For this reason, storing the proto files in `src/` is not applicable, as they would appear in version control every time. **So where to put them?**

Comment: Hi, may I ask how do you use gpb? I don't know how to let it compile .proto files.

Comment: Try `gpb_compile:file("your.proto", Options)`, and `Options` could be  `[strings_as_binaries, use_packages, include_as_lib]`. You also may want to try an extension I wrote for gpb which sits on top of it for more convenient bindings: https://github.com/squidfunk/gpb-bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely put them in the src directory. You then explicitly *include* the `.proto` files in the source control system while you make sure to *exclude* the corresponding `.erl` from the source control system. All you then need are rules in build tool (make, rebar, ...) to generate the `.erl` files from the `.proto` files and then compile them. Depending on source control system you will probably not have to even delete them (this works with git).

Comment: Okay, include the proto files and exclude the rest, sounds legit.

Comment: I have personally done this with files generated using `leex` (scanner generator) an `yecc` (parser generator). Include the `.xrl` and `.yrl` files and exclude the generated `.erl` files

Answer (score 4):

put them in the src directory using a naming rule (like a gpb_ prefix) that allow the source control system to ignore them.