# Can ANTLR hide the first line message in the auto-generated files?

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr

I use ANTLR 3.5 in my work. 
However, the auto-generated files (lexer and parser) always get the message:

```
"$ANTLR 3.5 D:\\PATH_OF_ANTLR_FILE\\Expression.g 2013-04-10 15:34:48"
```

Is there anyway to hide this message?
I want hide the message since I take these files into version control system.
The version control system will get conflict message if the date info in this message is mismatch with earlier one.

Comment: In my opinion, generated code should not be checked into source control. You should only check-in your antlr grammar file, not the lexer and parser generated off it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893913/should-i-store-generated-code-in-source-control.

Comment: Why VCS will get conflict???

Comment: @dogbane but in my case, not every member in our team have installed ANTLR plugin (ex: front end programmer, PM... ). Do not check auto-generated code into VCS means everyone should install ANTLR plugin. It's inconvenient.

Comment: @Andremoniy since I checkout previous version code the ANTLR will re-generated the code again. The generated comment with date info will change (become newer). when I checkout the latest version, conflict happen.

Comment: Conflict can occur only in case, when two (or more) programmers commit different changes in same lines of same file. In your case I couldn't understand the issue

Comment: @Andremoniy If my commit history look like this A--B--C--D, the A is the first version and the D is latest version. When I checkout version B, the ANTLR will auto-generate new code since the g file is different between B and D. After that, when I checkout back to version D the conflict happen since the first line is different.

Comment: To simplify this question. Can I just hide the message or show the message without the date in the end?

Comment: I don't believe `antlr` has an option to turn this off. However, you can probably run a script (using the `sed` command for example) to remove this line after `antlr` has generated the files.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR does not have a way to disable this message. However, this does not cause a problem with source control since the recommended usage for *at least* the Java, CSharp2, and CSharp3 targets involves automatic generation of parsers from the grammars at build time, and the generated files themselves are excluded from source control.

Comment: That is the usual way, but there are certainly scenarios where you want to check in the generated code.  For example, I might be writing a library to work with SQL queries in C++.  Part of the implementation could be an Antlr grammar that generated a C++ parser.  When I distribute my library to C++ users, I do not want to force them to install Antlr and Java.  I want to distribute the generated C++ files.  So in that case, I want the .g files in version control, but I also want the generated headers.