# commit generated code to svn from netbeans

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, jaxb

I have created an EJB project in netbeans 8.0.2. I am creating webservice client. Also I am creating pojos using jaxb binding. All these files are saved by netbeans in generated-sources folder under build folder. When I try to commit in netbeans, it doesn't give me any option to commit the files under generated-sources folder. One option is to go into file explorer and commit to svn from there. However I was looking for an option to commit these files from within netbeans itself. Any option to do the same?

Comment: Storing generated code in repository is usually not advised. Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893913/should-i-store-generated-code-in-source-control) for details.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I understand that it is not advisable. But in my case it is required since I have to carry out some minor modifications in the generated files.eg. adding the handlerchain annotation. So if I don't commit them, I'll have to carry out this minor modifications everytime the code is checked out and compiled.

Comment: @wib - Is it possible to either have the code generator add the annotations, or have your build script/makefile add them for you?  That would solve the problem, plus make your life easier.